# Weka ThresholdSelector from commandline

Tags: machine-learning, classification, weka

I have ThresholdSelector classifier installed in Weka and it works fine in Weka's GUI but I can't run it from commandline. I try:

java -classpath weka.jar weka.classifiers.meta.ThresholdSelector -C 5 -X 3 -E 1 -R 0 -M FMEASURE -S 1 -W weka.classifiers.functions.Logistic -- -R 1.0E-8 -M -1 -num-decimal-places 4

just as I do with any other classifier but I get an error: "Could not find or load main class weka.classifiers.meta.ThresholdSelector"

Is it because the classifier isn't one of the basic ones and was downloaded via the Packet Manager? From Weka's docummentation I found out that it implements "CommandlineRunnable" interface, which suggests there should be a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extensions come in separate `.jar` files that also need to be on your classpath.

The command line doesn't automatically load extensions.

Comment: Ok. I got it work like this:
"weka.Run .ThresholdSelector -C 5 -X 3 -E 1 -R 0 -M FMEASURE -S 1 -W weka.classifiers.trees.RandomForest -- -P 100 -I 125 -num-slots 1 -K 52 -M 1.0 -V 0.001 -S 1"

Now I'd like to run it from java code. I have the thresholdSelector.jar added to my project. How can I use it? What namespace does it belong to?